how to get CSRF Token embeded in html using HttpRequest
i`m scraping a website with http requests , the website has csrf token and its embeded to html and appears on while http request like that
</script><script type="text/javascript" nonce="223268a4-c5d4-4f9d-8c60-e17006a0ad71" id="storeScript">window.__REDUX_STORE__ = {"registrationErrors":{"status":"ok","code":"","text":""},"signup":{"mode":"with-suggest-to-restore-by-phone","tmxSession":"0715b3b8-c544-4a08-a374-c5258347ec57","config":{"registerWithFullPersonalInfoOrigins":["full_personal_info","full_personal_info_neo","flowservice_sales_funnel","market_touch_full_personal_info_checkout","market_desktop_full_personal_info_checkout"]}},"tracks":
"csrf":"d954e2e23e660287d9ed039494a78ae886a89065:1715767102780","currentUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fpassport.yandex.com\u002Fauth\u002Freg","experiments":{

my question how can i read the csrf token from the window.REDUX_STORE by http requests
i execpet to get csrf token from the window.REDUX_STORE with http requests
